# Diferentation equation word problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Barbara weighs 60 kg and is on a diet of 1600 calories per
day, of which 850 are used automatically by basal metabolism.
She spends about 15 cal/kg/day times her weight doing exercise. If 1 kg of fat contains 10,000 cal and we assume that 
the storage of calories in the form of fat is efﬁcient,
formulate a differential equation and solve it to ﬁnd her
weight as a function of time. Does her weight ultimately
approach an equilibrium weight?  To begin with, how do i form a differential equation for the given word problem.

Answer (score 0):

${{\dfrac{dw}{dt}}= {\dfrac{750t - 15\times{w}\times{t}}{10000}}}$

I think this is the differential equation. Here ${w}$ is the weight and ${t}$ the time. :))

Comment: Use \dfrac for big font of a fraction.